# Make offset, absolute pixel position image grid responsive & in order

Tags: html, css, image, grid, responsive

I hope someone might be able to help. I have an offset image grid (link below), which are all absolutely positioned in an outer div.

http://hughjan.us/stack-demo/stack-demo.html

Currently all of the images are exactly the size they need to be, which doesn't help with filling any size screen. So, this grid needs to be responsive, to scale with the browser and also stack vertically, one below the other & in the order of the numbers, on smaller screen sizes.
I appreciate this is maybe two problems; responsive & stacking in a certain order. I'll split it up if it helps.

```css
/* home page image styles */

#home-outer {
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  width: 1024px;
  height: 779px;
}

#demo-our-work_ {
  position: absolute;
  left: 446px;
  top: 0px;
  width: 410px;
  height: 229px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

#demo-our-work_:hover .homeoverlay {
  width: 100%;
}

#demo-check-availability_ {
  position: absolute;
  left: 219px;
  top: 51px;
  width: 216px;
  height: 178px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

#demo-check-availability_:hover .homeoverlay {
  width: 100%;
}

#demo-voiceovers_ {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 239px;
  width: 376px;
  height: 241px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

#demo-voiceovers_:hover .homeoverlay {
  width: 100%;
}

#demo-logo_ {
  position: absolute;
  left: 378px;
  top: 244px;
  width: 268px;
  height: 241px;
}

#demo-voicereels_ {
  position: absolute;
  left: 649px;
  top: 239px;
  width: 375px;
  height: 263px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

#demo-voicereels_:hover .homeoverlay {
  width: 100%;
}

#demo-about_ {
  position: absolute;
  left: 101px;
  top: 491px;
  width: 348px;
  height: 153px;
}

#demo-about_:hover .homeoverlay {
  width: 100%;
}

#demo-our-history_ {
  position: absolute;
  left: 458px;
  top: 491px;
  width: 181px;
  height: 288px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

#demo-our-history_:hover .homeoverlay {
  width: 100%;
}

#demo-studios_ {
  position: absolute;
  left: 649px;
  top: 512px;
  width: 320px;
  height: 222px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

#demo-studios_:hover .homeoverlay {
  width: 100%;
}

#demo-additional-services_ {
  position: absolute;
  left: 274px;
  top: 653px;
  width: 175px;
  height: 113px;
  background-color: #000000;
}

#demo-additional-services_:hover .homeoverlay {
  width: 100%;
}


/*homepage roll over styles */

.homeoverlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: .8s ease;
  z-index: 9999;
}

.homeoverlay span {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1;
  /* fixes overlap error in IE7/8, 
         make sure you have an empty gif */
  background-image: url('empty.gif');
}

.hometext {
  white-space: nowrap;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hometext a {
  color: white;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 20px;
}


/*end home page roll over styles */


/* rollover for about text */

.about-text-layer {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
  color: #fff;
  visibility: hidden;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

#demo-about_:hover .about-text-layer {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}

.about-text {
  transition: .9s;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  padding: 0 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
}

#demo-about_:hover .about-text {
  transform: translateX(0);
}


/* end rolloever for about text */


/* end home page image styles */


/*main rollover styles */

.rollover-container {
  position: relative;
  max-width: 300px;
  max-height: 300px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 0 5px 0;
}

.rolloverlay {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0;
  height: 100%;
  transition: .8s ease;
}

.rollover-container:hover .rolloverlay {
  width: 100%;
}

.rollover-text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

```html
<div id="home-outer">

  <div id="demo-our-work_">
    <img id="demo-check-availability" src="http://hughjan.us/stack-demo/image6.jpg" border="0" alt="demo Check Availability" />
    <div class="homeoverlay"><a href="http://hughjan.us/stack-demo/our-work/"><span></span></a>
      <div class="hometext"><a href="http://hughjan.us/stack-demo/our-work/">Our Work</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="demo-check-availability_">
    <img id="demo-check-availability" src="http://hughjan.us/stack-demo/image8.jpg" border="0" alt="demo Check Availability" />
    <div class="homeoverlay"><a href="http://hughjan.us/stack-demo/check-availability/"><span></span></a>
      <div class="hometext"><a href="http://hughjan.us/stack-demo/check-availability/">Check Availability</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="demo-voiceovers_">
    <img id="demo-voiceovers" src="http://hughjan.us/stack-demo/image2.jpg" border="0" alt="demo" />
    <div class="homeoverlay"><a href="http://hughjan.us/stack-demo/#/"><span></span></a>
      <div class="hometext"><a href="http://hughjan.us/stack-demo/#/">Link 2</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="demo-logo_">
    <img id="demo_logo" src="http://hughjan.us/stack-demo/image1.jpg" width="268" height="241" alt="" />
  </div>
  <div id="demo-voicereels_">
    <img id="demo-voicereels" src="http://hughjan.us/stack-demo/image3.jpg" border="0" alt="demo - link 3" />
    <div class="homeoverlay"><a href="http://hughjan.us/stack-demo/#"><span></span></a>
      <div class="hometext"><a href="http://hughjan.us/stack-demo/#">Link 3</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="demo-about_">
    <img id="demo-about" src="http://hughjan.us/stack-demo/image7.jpg" alt="demo - About" />
    <div class="about-text-layer">
      <p class="about-text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Aenean commodo ligula eget dolor. Aenean massa. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Donec quam felis, ultricies nec, pellentesque eu, pretium
        quis, sem. Nulla consequat massa quis enim. </p>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="demo-our-history_">
    <img id="demo-our-history" src="http://hughjan.us/stack-demo/image5.jpg" border="0" alt="demo - Our History" />
    <div class="homeoverlay"><a href="http://hughjan.us/stack-demo/our-history/"><span></span></a>
      <div class="hometext"><a href="http://hughjan.us/stack-demo/our-history/">Our History</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="demo-studios_">
    <img id="demo-studios" src="http://hughjan.us/stack-demo/image4.jpg" border="0" alt="demo - link 4" />
    <div class="homeoverlay"><a href="http://hughjan.us/stack-demo/studios/"><span></span></a>
      <div class="hometext"><a href="http://hughjan.us/stack-demo/#/">Link 4</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="demo-additional-services_">
    <img id="demo-additional-services" src="http://hughjan.us/stack-demo/image9.jpg" border="0" alt="demo - Additional Services" />
    <div class="homeoverlay"><a href="http://hughjan.us/stack-demo/additional-services/"><span></span></a>
      <div class="hometext"><a href="http://hughjan.us/stack-demo/additional-services/">Additional<br>Services</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm not sure if this way of positioning is the best for this layout? My css skills are limited, I'm afraid to say. I need to make the whole layout have perhaps an 80% centered width at fuller sizes but stack the images in numbered order for smaller screens.
I'm aware of media queries for smaller screen sizes and that 'display:inline; with a min width would drop the images below one another but the absolute positioning that has allowed me to arrange these images causes me problems.

I realizes whilst writing that I'm not very good at describing this but I hope it's understandable.
Any help gratefully received